# Appending an asterisk to a label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need an asterisk on a label.  I have created an editor for

```
 @if (ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x, ViewData).IsRequired)
  {
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m, null, "*")
  }
```

I thought this would just take the label and then append the asterisk, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? am I using the wrong overload?

Comment: Replace null with the name of the property from `ModelMetaData` and append an asterisk to that. Something like `@Html.LabelFor(m => m, ModelMetaData.PropertyName)`.

Comment: can you give a sample?

Comment: Does the code I supplied give you enough to work from?

Comment: Rowan - thank it helped - i used the following @Html.LabelFor(m => m, ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x=> x, ViewData).DisplayName + "*")

Comment: Asterisk not Asterix, Asterix is the guy from `Asterix and Obelix` who hit the roman-soldiers.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a Html helper? if not you can just add a span with an asterisk. like so.

```
 @if (ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x, ViewData).IsRequired)
  {
       <span>*</span>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are overloading a text from `Property Name` to `Label Text`

The `Label For` will be useful when you want to assign `textbox, checkbox, radio` labels like below:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @maxlength = 30, placeholder = "First Name (Required)" })
```

At Browser Side Html will be rendered like below :

```
<label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
<input id="FirstName" type="text" value="RJK" placeholder="First Name (Required)" name="FirstName" maxlength="30">
```

If you assign Label Text as `*` even you have property name  `@Html.LabelFor(m => m, null, "*")` then Label Text will be over written like:

`<label for="m">*</label>`

Instead of doing this you can use :

```
@Html.Label(Model.BedNo + "*")

@Html.Label("*")
```

**Or**

The Star can be out side of the razor:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BedNo)*
```

Refer Here : [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should decorated your models with the [DisplayNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx).

```
    [DisplayName("First Name*")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

**View** - You don't need to append anything.

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a html helper for this. Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
public static class LabelHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        string labelText)
    {
        string labelHtml = string.Empty;    

        if (ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).IsRequired)
        {
            string spanHtml = "<span class='required'>*</span>";
            labelHtml = "<label>" + labelText + spanHtml + "</label>";
        }
        else
        {
            labelHtml = "<label>" + labelText + "</label>";
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(labelHtml);
    }
}
```

to use in the view, an example:

`@Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.FirstName, "First Name")`

That way, all the logic is contained in the helper method, no need to add 'if' statements, or whatever, to the view. If you need to, you can access `PropertyName` from here:

`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData).PropertyName`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "label-Name" })<span style="Color:Red">*</span>
```

Comment: so that all fields which are marked required are shown with * mark , you don't have to customize it every time.